# Form is not sending data via Post

Tags: php, forms, post

I know that this question could seem stupid, but I'm trying to resolve the problem for a long time. I read topics about form not sending data, but the main cause of the problem was miss of name attribute. I'm really confused due to the fact that things seems to be simple enough in my case. I have a form:

```
<h3>Send a message</h3>
<div class="status alert alert-success" style="display: none"></div>
<form id="main-contact-form" class="contact-form" name="contact-form" method="post" action="sendemail.php">
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control" required="required" placeholder="Name">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="email" name="email" class="form-control" required="required" placeholder="Email ID">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <textarea name="message" id="message" required="required" class="form-control" rows="4" placeholder="Enter your message"></textarea>
    </div>                        
     <button type="submit" name="submit_mail" class="btn btn-primary pull-right">Send</button>
</form>
```

And with I'm trying to send email using php:

```
<?php
include 'php/functions.php';

$status = array(
    'type'=>'success',
    'message'=>'Thank you for contact us. As early as possible  we will contact you '
    );
$name = @trim(stripslashes($_POST['name'])); 
$email = @trim(stripslashes($_POST['email'])); 
$subject = @trim(stripslashes($_POST['subject'])); 
$message = @trim(stripslashes($_POST['message'])); 

$email_from = $email;
    $email_to = 'correct@email.com';//replace with your email
    $body = 'Name:' . $name . "\n\n" . 'Email: ' . $email . "\n\n" . 'Subject: ' . $subject . "\n\n" . 'Message: ' . $message;
    $success = @mail($email_to, $subject, $body, 'From: <'.$email_from.'>');
    echo json_encode($status);
    die;
?>
```

The result is: email is send to me, but its content is empty. I used small debug thing to set name to *'No name'* if the POST is not set. And in the email body I get *'Name: No Name;'*
The issue seems to be simple but I cannot resolve it because I'm novice to Web Development. Anyway, I would appreciate any suggestions.
Best Regards,
Pavel

Comment: As I understand, POST request is not even sent. I used this check
`if($_POST){ .... } `
And it always returns false

Comment: please update your question...

Comment: @user3284463 Updated. Thank you for interest

Answer (score 0):

Please see that your submit button doesn't have any name attribute.

Change it to:

```
<button type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-primary pull-right">Send</button>
```

Also, you may wanna recheck your login. Your mail function should be within this if (isset(...)). Otherwise, a blank mail would be send to the user even if the form values aren't saved to the database.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I modified my input to:
    `<input type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-primary pull-right"/>`
The result is still the same - I''m getting an empty mail

Comment: Sorry, there's one more thing I missed out. This should be a button tag instead of an input. Please see my edited answer.

Comment: I really appreciate your help but the problem has not gone